# What is the genre of the song "You in me"?

Tags: identify-this-genre

[You in me](https://youtu.be/tz23WFb8HM0) a song by a co-ed korean band named KARD. Genre? Sub-genre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You in me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_in_Me) is released by [DSP Media](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSP_Media), an entertainment company that releases tracks in K-pop, R&B, EDM and Hip hop. This song belongs to genre [Dance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_dance_music), sub-genre [K-pop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-pop), as it's pop, Korean and influenced by pop, EDM and modern R&B.